# codeigniter how to connect second database based on dynamic values

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to import data from other database with dynamic connection

in codeigniter user input the database credential in the form and than I want to connect that database and import some data in the primary database. the question is how to set the second database connection with the dynamic values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is your **first db connection** from **application/config/database.php**

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'first_db',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

and this is second db connection function from model or controller or helper your choice.

```
private function second_db(){
    return $db['second'] = array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'second_db',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array(),
        'save_queries' => TRUE
    );
}
private function first_db(){
        return $db['second'] = array(
            'dsn'   => '',
            'hostname' => 'localhost',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'database' => 'first_db',
            'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
            'dbprefix' => '',
            'pconnect' => FALSE,
            'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
            'cache_on' => FALSE,
            'cachedir' => '',
            'char_set' => 'utf8',
            'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
            'swap_pre' => '',
            'encrypt' => FALSE,
            'compress' => FALSE,
            'stricton' => FALSE,
            'failover' => array(),
            'save_queries' => TRUE
        );
    }
```

if you set up your settings then you can switch your database with this code

```
$this->load->database(first_db(), TRUE);
$this->load->database(second_db(), TRUE);
```